# OneDrive API: create Subscription

Tags: office365, onedrive

I work with oneDrive (I can list or upload files without problems)

Now, I sent post request to `api.onedrive.com`

```
POST /v1.0/drive/items/A1EAE8A1F0669564!144/subscriptions HTTP/1.1
Host: api.onedrive.com
Authorization: bearer EwAQA61DBAAU...7lYJ2MtQEIPw7FMEAg==
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache

{ "notificationUrl": "https://odwebhooktest.azurewebsites.net/notification/listen", "expirationDateTime": "2018-01-01T11:23:00.000Z" }
```

This request is same as in Documentation https://dev.onedrive.com/webhooks/create-subscription.htm

But I received response

> `{"error":{"code":"invalidRequest","message":"Bad Argument"}}`

What I do wrong?

Comment: Could you attach the response headers to this question? It'll give us a little more insight in to what's going on. You could also try setting the expiration to a value not so far in the future (e.g. 3 months) and see if that works.

Answer (score 2):

The expirationDateTime value needs to be within the next 60 days. You've set it to two years out.

You can update the expirationDateTime value frequently to keep a subscription active, but the date can never be more than 60 days from the time the request is issued.

Answer (score 0):

From another page of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/msgraph-changenotifications-trackchanges/4-change-notifications):

> Create subscription
> Next, create a change notification subscription by submitting an HTTP POST request to the subscriptions endpoint: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions. The payload of this request will contain the specifics of the subscription (covered later in this unit).

Note that this is also described in [the documentation link you provided](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/subscription_post_subscriptions?view=odsp-graph-online).  It is possible, of course, that the behaviour and the associated documentation has changed since you asked the question.